# how to enable throws exception using JPA 2.1 and eclipseLink 2.5.2

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, bean-validation

I'm using JPA 2.1 and i want to enable to throws exception from entity when validation failed this is field on my entity i have to create `<h:messages />` to my JSF page to show this problem and i can't handle it in another way.

**How I can throw the exception if I didn't put value in this field?**,

I want to know how I can enable the exception and I will handle this exception

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "room_name")
private String roomName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can throw the exception if I didn't put value in this field?

---

In adding @NotNull Constraint

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "room_name")
private String roomName;
```

Comment: In Web.xml add this snippet :<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>